# How to disable appending model accessors during tests?

Tags: laravel, phpunit, faker

Am writing a test where I need to make a new instance of an Eloquent model `Video` using Faker factory builder

```php
$user = create(User::class);
$video = create(Video::class, 'make')->toArray(); // toArray serializes the model to include accessors
$user->videos()->create($video); // <--- Error occurs here
```

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table videos has no column named views

`create()` is a helper function wrapper around `factory()` in an autoloaded file

```php
/**
 * Generate a fake model
 *
 * Call the factory helper function on given model
 *
 * @param Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model $model Eloquent Model
 * @param string $method create or make the model
 * @param int $times How many model instances to return
 * @param array $properties Model attributes to override in factory
 *
 * @return mixed Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|array|collection
 **/
function create($model, $method = 'create', $times = null, $properties = [])
{
    return factory($model, $times)->$method($properties);
}
```

The model `Video` appends a `views` accessor (unrelated to database), here's the model

```php
class Video extends BaseModel
{
    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = ['views', 'length', 'timesReported'];
}
```

The `views` accessor is in the `BaseModel`, here's that

```php
class BaseModel extends Model
{
    public $guarded = []; // Yolo!!

    /**
     * Get the user who owns the model.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    // Get model views count from Redis
    public function getViewsAttribute()
    {
        return \Redis::zscore('popular_'.$this->getTable(), $this->id);
    }
}
```

Here's the `VideoFactory` in case that's helpful

```php
$factory->define(App\Video::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'title' => $faker->realText(50, 2),
        'uploader' => 'Unknown',
        'duration' => '00:00:00',
        'thumbnail' => $faker->imageUrl(),
        'poster' => $faker->imageUrl(),
        'slides' => $faker->imageUrl(),
        'hls' => $faker->url,
        'mp4' => $faker->url,
        '_3gp' => $faker->url,
        'quality' => $faker->randomElement(['normal', 'hd']),
    ];
});
```

And the `videos` table migration

```php
Schema::create('videos', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->json('title'); // MySQL doesn't allow uniqueness on json type columns
    $table->enum('quality', ['normal', 'hd']);
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('uploader');
    $table->time('duration');
    $table->string('thumbnail')->unique();
    $table->string('poster')->unique();
    $table->string('slides')->unique();
    $table->string('hls')->unique();
    $table->string('mp4', 350)->unique();
    $table->string('_3gp', 350)->unique();
    $table->json('slug');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

#### How to exclude appended accessors to model factory calls?

I thought of using `array_except` but then I would have to modify the test every time I append another accessor

Comment: if you don't need casts or the appends/hidden or relationships you could just grab the attributes `$model->getAttributes()` ... also could define `fillable` on that model

Comment: `$video = create(Video::class, 'make')->getAttributes();` works! thanks, you can make it an answer (tho I already found a simpler solution xD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `save` instead of `create` on the relationship since you already have an instance of `Video` with the attributes you wanted from the factory:

```
$user = create(User::class);
$video = create(Video::class, 'make');
$user->videos()->save($video);
```

This way you avoid needing to pull the attributes to then create a new instance of the same model and call save on it (which is what `create` is doing).

If you really want to use `create` on that relationship, which means you need the attributes to pass to `create` you could call `getAttributes` instead of `toArray()`:

```
$video = create(Video::class, 'make')->getAttributes();
$user->videos()->create($video);
```

Answer (score 1):

I also found that the factory builder has a `raw` method which only returns the array defined in the model factory

```php
$user = create(User::class);
$video = create(Video::class, 'raw');
$user->videos()->create($video);
```

No need to serialize, `raw` is already an array

Comment: Yeah I ended up going with this, sorry :') but thanks for the help